# Can I get an example of a function that satisfies the finite dimensional MPT?

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The finite dimensional Mountain Pass Theorem states:
Theorem (Finite Dimensional MPT, Courant). Suppose that
ϕ ∈ C1(Rn,R) is proper and possesses two distinct strict relative
minima x1 and x2. Then ϕ possesses a third critical point x3 distinct
from x1 and x2, characterized by
ϕ(x3) = inf Σ∈Γmax x∈Σ ϕ(x)
where Γ = {Σ ⊂ Rn;Σ is compact and connected and x1,x2 ∈ Σ}[image: I added a screenshot of the theorem for better reading.]

By proper Courant means the function is coercive. So I am trying to find a finite dimensional function that has two minima and is coercive for my thesis so I can study it and write an algorithm to find the saddle point.

As a side question I don't particularly understand what the inf max means. I think it's the smallest of the maximums but I'm not really sure. Thank you for taking the time to read this question and taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct such a function for example as follows.
Consider the one dimensional function $$ y = (x-1)^2 (x+1)^2$$
It has two minima at $x = +1,-1$ and a relative maximum for $x=0$.
Then you can get a  two-dimensional function satisfying your requirements by considering for example $$ z = (x-1)^2 (x+1)^2 +y^2$$
[image]

You can verify by direct calculation using partial derivatives that there are three critical points.

With regards to your side question, $\inf \max$ refers to the infimum of the maxima, not the minimum. The minimum need not be attained: there not need to be a smallest of the maxima, in the same fashion the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ does not admit a minimum, yet the infinimum is $0$.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a general theory for turning 2d curves into 3d curves? I was also wondering if there was a way I could extrapolate this into higher dimensions? Like take your 2d example and create a 4d example? I want to see if my algorithm could still find the saddle point then. Thank you again for all the help!

Comment: With regards to turning 2d curves into 3 surfaces and a general thoery, I guess the matter depends on what characteristics you want the 3d curve to inherit from the lower dmensional case. With regards to going from 2d to 4d, I believe adding a term like $w^2$ should do the trick, similarly to what done so far: then the 3 surfaces presented above will be the section for $w=0$ of the 4-d surface, and any variation in $w$ will yield higher function values, leaving the minima unaltered. I am glad the answer was of some help, I would be humbled if you considered ticking it as an accepted answer.